# vertical bars not aligned with the x-axis label and last bar rendered outside the x-axis range - D3 js - simple bar with fixed width

Tags: d3.js

I'm having challenges in setting the bar (fixed width) position aligned correctly width the x-axis label.

The bars and the x-ticks are not aligned correctly and also the last bar is rendered after the max xscale range.

Appreciate any help in fixing this issue.

Please check the sample here - https://jsfiddle.net/sjselvan/wsy5frh2/29/ - updated and fixed version

```js
function generateChart(){
  const data = [{
   label: 100,
   value: 10
},
{
   label: 200,
   value: 20
},
{
   label: 300,
   value: 30
},
{
   label: 400,
   value: 40
},
{
   label: 500,
   value: 50
}];

let margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,500]).range([0,width]);
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,50]).range([height,0]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

console.log(d3.select('#chart'));
let svg = d3.select('#chart')
               .append("svg")
          .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
          .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g")
          .attr("transform", 
               "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
                   
                   
svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", "-.55em")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Value ($)");

  svg.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "steelblue")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.label); })
      .attr("width", 15)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value); });                   
}


generateChart();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `x` value of the bars, which sets the left-hand edge of the bars, using the same scale as the x axis. So, it makes sense that the left-hand edge of the bar representing 100 is lined up with the 100 tick in the axis.

In order to line up the bars, you need to move them to the left by half of their width. You would need to make the bar width an even number so that the bars fit nicely.

```
const barWidth = 16;

svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.label) - (barWidth / 2); })
  .attr("width", barWidth)
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.value); });
```

*However*, I would say that it doesn't really make sense for this chart to be a bar chart. Bars usually represent *nominal* (Banana, Apple, Pear), or *ordinal* values. Whereas your chart seems to more suit a line, or a scattergraph.

But if you do mean to use the numbers as labels, you will be better off using a [band scale](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band-scales) which will line up the bars above the labels nicely.